# Hetrogenous gridgain grid configuration

Tags: gridgain

Is there any guidance on how to configure a grid with nodes that have different roles?

For example I have some nodes that can store data and others that should only have a near cache - effectively clients of the grid.

Is this done by specifying separate config files for each node type or by overriding settings on different nodes in code?

Also generally what are the resolution rules for deploying differing configurations for the same entity (e.g. a particular named cache), or is this the mechanism to solve the above?

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can configure same cache on different grid nodes with different distribution modes. I think this link is what you are looking for: [Cache Distribution Mode](http://atlassian.gridgain.com/wiki/display/GG60/Cache+Distribution+Models#CacheDistributionModels-CacheDistributionMode)

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. This didn't work for me. I start the storage node with PARTIONED_ONLY, the client with NEAR_ONLY, and then try and put from the client, I get a NPE on both nodes. If I set both to PARTIIONED_ONLY it works fine.

Comment: I now have this working the 'storage' node requires NEAR_PARTITIONED, the 'client' node NEAR_ONLY.

Comment: @user3572982 It should work with PARTITIONED_ONLY mode. Can you provide a code sample for what it is you are doing?